# Excel: How to add double quotes to strings only in CSV file

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I want to create a CSV file from Excel in which string values should be in double quotes and date values should be in MM/dd/yyyy format. All the numeric and Boolean values should be without quotes.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Can i suggest storing dates in ISO yyyy-MM-dd format? It'll save you internationalisation issues.

Answer (score 7):

It's kind of scary that Excel doesn't let you specify formats.  Here's a MrExcel link that might prove useful to you as well.

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=320531

Here's the code from that site:

```
Sub CSVFile()

Dim SrcRg As Range
Dim CurrRow As Range
Dim CurrCell As Range
Dim CurrTextStr As String
Dim ListSep As String
Dim FName As Variant
FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "CSV File (*.csv), *.csv")

If FName <> False Then
  ListSep = Application.International(xlListSeparator)
  If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Set SrcRg = Selection
  Else
    Set SrcRg = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  End If    
  Open FName For Output As #1    
  For Each CurrRow In SrcRg.Rows
    CurrTextStr = ""
    For Each CurrCell In CurrRow.Cells
      CurrTextStr = CurrTextStr & """" & CurrCell.Value & """" & ListSep
    Next
    While Right(CurrTextStr, 1) = ListSep
      CurrTextStr = Left(CurrTextStr, Len(CurrTextStr) - 1)
    Wend    
    Print #1, CurrTextStr    
  Next    
  Close #1    
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to use VBA to do this. The `SaveAs` method of the `Workbook` object only lets you choose pre-defined formats and the `xlCSV` one does not delimit strings with double-quotes.

To do this in VBA:

```
Dim fileOut As Integer

fileOut = FreeFile
Open "C:\foo.csv" For Output As #fileOut

Write #fileOut, 14, "Stack Overflow", Date, True

Close #fileOut
```

(NB `Date` is a VBA statement that returns the current system date as a Variant of sub-type Date)

If you then examine the file in Notepad:

> 14,"Stack Overflow",#2009-05-12#,#TRUE#

The string has been delimited as required, the date converted to universal format and both the date and boolean are delimited with # signs.

To read the data back in use the `Input #` statement which will interpret all of the values appropriately.

If you want to write part of a line and then finish writing it later then:

```
Write #fileOut, 14, "Stack Overflow";
Write #fileOut, Date, True
```

produces the same result as the original program. The semi-colon at the end of the first statement prevents a new line being started

Strings with embedded double-quotes will cause problems so you'll need to remove or replace those characters